# Strip Out strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

How we can strip out below string

```
*** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) *** December 27, 2006 11:36:00  NPF  $36.90 from PO eff. Nov 1st 2006 $38.10 $38.90  Criterion CL $28.90   *** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) *** February 6, 2007 13:11:00  NPF 36.90 no change, less 1.5% ins, less 2% pay disc, less 1.30 ocean ++  GLD 30.90 (fr 28.90), less 1.5% ins, less 2% pay disc, less 1.26 ocean ++     *** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) *** October 4, 2007 10:13:00  Per ML price decrease effective 08/01/07. CL from $ 30.90 to $28.90 NPF from $36.90 to $37.90 due to Tillotson   ** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) ***  May 29, 2007 at  1:02pm  2006 Spiff $11,883 2007 Spiff $13,700.    *** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) *** December 6, 2007 10:51:00  Price increase in Criterion CL 3/6/2008 See e-mail to Jeff Sherman CL from $28.90 to $30.15 or $30.40     *** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) *** March 31, 2008 16:01:00  3/6/08 CL $31.50,  5/1/08 NPF $38.95     *** CYNTHIAH (Cynthia Hernandez) *** May 8, 2008 09:51:00  Per ML Remind him when HS stops buying from Adenna about insurance.  Do we need 3 mil insurance. Possible solution:  Sell thru Dermatec on LTL biz.    *** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) *** August 29, 2008 11:05:00  See HS Container cost calc excel for most current 40' pricing.    *** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) *** December 17, 2008 16:17:00  Price change - 60 days notice in advanced, multiple times.     *** EVANGC (Evangelene Cheng) *** February 17, 2012 14:02:00  JES NOTE:  COMMENT:  HESC01: When shipping Adenna product 84+ CS. HESC02:  Container Orders HESC03:  When shippign Adenna Product less than 84 CS; (Ship-Collect).      *** MASTER (Supervisor) *** March 5, 2014 02:32:11 ~~deleted=1  Test  *** MASTER (Supervisor) *** March 5, 2014 03:06:33 ~~deleted=1  sdfdf  *** MASTER (Supervisor) *** March 5, 2014 20:36:05 ~~deleted=1  Test  *** MASTER (Supervisor) *** March 5, 2014 20:43:07 ~~deleted=1  Test Note
```

into following format

```
1st Column : String between *** , only first occurrences and neglect others 
2nd Column : Date and Time
3rd Column : Remaining String
```

Please help.

Comment: have you googled on how to use substring and charindex ??

Comment: What have *you* tried? Can you show us your failed attempt?

Comment: I have googled it but i haven't found any solution for that.

Comment: If the current string is something you retrieve or get from the code, then use the inbuilt string functions in order to get the strings. and then insert them into the table by supplying the variables that hold the string portions

Comment: Actually I doing queries in SQL. I want move this data into another table's columns. I have used PATINDEX for that three star * but not getting how to strip out the data contains between that three star * and the date from the string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so experienced in these functions but this is all I came up with:

```
DECLARE @MyString as varchar(500)
SET @MyString='*** MIGUELP (Miguel Padilla) ***  August 14, 2012 12:51:33  08/14/2012 -  Always email PRO# the next day the order ships.'
DECLARE @RevString as varchar(500)
SET @RevString=REVERSE(@MyString)

SELECT Substring(@MyString,5,charindex(' *',@MyString)-4) as FirstCol
,SUBSTRING(@MyString,charindex(' *** ',@MyString)+4,38) as DateTime
,Reverse(substring(@RevString,1,charindex('-',@RevString)-1)) as Remaining
```

And I am sure, there will be a better and efficient way.

See [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/31061)

Comment: how did you fix the values 38 ?? since the first name between the *** could always vary is it not ? I tried doing this dynamically but could nt, thats why i am asking the reason behind the 38 :)

Comment: 38 is the ***length*** of the substring (not the last index). So I hope varying the text between *** would not affect that.

Comment: [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/883d5/31) has the answer but then its not the correct way.. i believe :(

Answer (score 0):

Its really quite difficult to give you a straight answer on this one not knowing all the edge cases you wish to support, but here are a couple techniques I have used to extract data from pseudo-delimited log messages like yours.

EDIT: Modified strategy following updated string. For the 2nd delimiter I am now using the end of the time (11:36:00) by looking for the first ":NN " set of chars. Hey, it doesnt have to be pretty :)

```
declare @s varchar(1000);
set @s = '*** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) *** December 27, 2006 11:36:00  NPF  $36.90 from PO eff. Nov 1st 2006 $38.10 $38.90  Criterion CL $28.90   *** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) *** February 6, 2007 13:11:00  NPF 36.90 no change, less 1.5% ins, less 2% pay disc, less 1.30 ocean ++  GLD 30.90 (fr 28.90), less 1.5% ins, less 2% pay disc, less 1.26 ocean ++     *** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) *** October 4, 2007 10:13:00  Per ML price decrease effective 08/01/07. CL from $ 30.90 to $28.90 NPF from $36.90 to $37.90 due to Tillotson   ** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) ***  May 29, 2007 at  1:02pm  2006 Spiff $11,883 2007 Spiff $13,700.    *** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) *** December 6, 2007 10:51:00  Price increase in Criterion CL 3/6/2008 See e-mail to Jeff Sherman CL from $28.90 to $30.15 or $30.40     *** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) *** March 31, 2008 16:01:00  3/6/08 CL $31.50,  5/1/08 NPF $38.95     *** CYNTHIAH (Cynthia Hernandez) *** May 8, 2008 09:51:00  Per ML Remind him when HS stops buying from Adenna about insurance.  Do we need 3 mil insurance. Possible solution:  Sell thru Dermatec on LTL biz.    *** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) *** August 29, 2008 11:05:00  See HS Container cost calc excel for most current 40'' pricing.    *** MAXWELLL (Maxwell Lee) *** December 17, 2008 16:17:00  Price change - 60 days notice in advanced, multiple times.     *** EVANGC (Evangelene Cheng) *** February 17, 2012 14:02:00  JES NOTE:  COMMENT:  HESC01: When shipping Adenna product 84+ CS. HESC02:  Container Orders HESC03:  When shippign Adenna Product less than 84 CS; (Ship-Collect).      *** MASTER (Supervisor) *** March 5, 2014 02:32:11 ~~deleted=1  Test  *** MASTER (Supervisor) *** March 5, 2014 03:06:33 ~~deleted=1  sdfdf  *** MASTER (Supervisor) *** March 5, 2014 20:36:05 ~~deleted=1  Test  *** MASTER (Supervisor) *** March 5, 2014 20:43:07 ~~deleted=1  Test Note'

;with x (doc) as
(
    select cast('<r>'+replace(stuff(@s, patindex('%:[0-9][0-9] %',@s)+3, 0, '***'), '***', '</r><r>')+'</r>' as xml)
)
select  [1st]=ltrim(rtrim(x.doc.query('data(r[position()=2])').value('.', 'varchar(100)'))),
        [2nd]=ltrim(rtrim(x.doc.query('data(r[position()=3])').value('.', 'varchar(100)'))),
        [3rd]=ltrim(rtrim(x.doc.query('data(r[position()=4])').value('.', 'varchar(100)')))
from x
```

Ok, I misunderstood. I thought you only wanted remaining up until the next entry.
The below might be cleaner and will not truncate the "remaining" column. Take a look at the columns `a,b,c` and see how it works. You should be able to play with them to fine tune your parse. If you want to iterate through the entries you'll need to do this sort of parsing in a loop:

```
;with c(a,b,c) as
(
            -- 1st ***
    select  charindex('***', @s, 0)+3,
            -- 2nd ***
            charindex('***', @s, 4),
            --the end of the time string
            patindex('%:[0-9][0-9] %',@s)+3 
)
select  [1st]=ltrim(rtrim(substring(@s, a, b-a))), 
        [2nd]=ltrim(rtrim(substring(@s, a+b, c-(a+b)))),
        [3rd]=ltrim(rtrim(substring(@s, c, len(@s)))),
        *
from    c;
```

Comment: thnk you..i am trying it for another string

Comment: we can not use - as second delimiter coz other strings also contains 'at' , '*', ' ' after datetime

Comment: @user3391278 Ok, I tried again with your updated sample.

Comment: Thank you very much..you are awesome..it is working..but it is escaping string after another occurrences of three star ***. Is it possible to create another row for that i mean split it  for another occurrences of three star??? and one more question how we can pass column into parameter..i m beginner..i dont know very much about that..shall i edit my question??